# Different operations onCreate in an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

I want to do different operations in onCreate() depending activities I come from.

I do that making this:

```
Activity A: 
   intent to activity B; 
   intent.putBoolean("name",boolean=false); 
   startActivity B.

Activity B: 
onCreate(){
   Boolean.getBoolean("name"); 
   if(boolean){
   }else{**make this**} 
on the other hand if click on a Button 
   onClick {starts activity C}.

Activity C: 
do things... 
-> if click on a Button -> 
onClick { 
   intent.putBoolean(boolean=true);
   starts ActivityB}

Activity B onCreate(){ 
   if(boolean){**make this**
   } else{}
```

My question: Can I do the same thing of better way?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `Can I do the same thing of better way?`?

Comment: *How can I do this of better way" Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the putExtra attribute of the Intent to pass the name of the Activity that is launching the current activity. For example, if activity A is calling C, then you would do this in the calling activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
    intent.putExtra("activity","A");
    startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity C:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
```

Now in the string activity you will get A and you will know you are coming from A. If you do the same for B, then your activity string will read B.

If C can only be launched via A or B, then you do not have any more to deal with but if it could be launched from HOME for example, then you might need an extra check in C.

Comment: I wanted do this whithout "if". But I think that's impossible. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it helped. I don't see a better way to do this.